# Swift typealias without type

Tags: swift, type-alias

What does typealias without the type on the right expression do?

In the example, what's the purpose of creating a BooleanLiteralType within BooleanLiteralConvertible when another typealias already exists outside of it? Are they related?

```
    /// Conforming types can be initialized with the Boolean literals
    /// `true` and `false`.
    protocol BooleanLiteralConvertible {
        typealias BooleanLiteralType

        /// Create an instance initialized to `value`.
        init(booleanLiteral value: Self.BooleanLiteralType)
    }


    /// The default type for an otherwise-unconstrained Boolean literal.
    typealias BooleanLiteralType = Bool
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It declares a type member for the protocol, which you can refer to in the protocol methods definition. This allows the definition of a generic protocol.

For instance

```
protocol Foo {
  typealias FooType

  func echo(x: FooType)
}

class Baz<T: Comparable>: Foo {
  typealias FooType = T

  func echo(x: FooType) {
    println(x)
  }
}

Baz().echo(2) // "2"
Baz().echo("hi") "hi"
```

The function `echo` is completely generic, as FooType is any type.
The class implementing the `Foo` protocol can then refine and specify `FooType` accordingly.

In the example we're using another generic type (`T`) so that `FooType` is not refined to only `Comparable` types.

---

Concerning the default typealias, this compiles

```
protocol Foo {
  typealias FooType

  func echo(x: FooType)
}

typealias FooType = Bool

class Bar: Foo {
  func echo(x: FooType) { // no local definition for `FooType`, default to `Bool`
    println(x)
  }
}
```

while this doesn't

```
protocol Foo {
  typealias FooType

  func echo(x: FooType)
}

class Bar: Foo {
  func echo(x: FooType) { // `FooType` can't be resolved as a valid type
    println(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - much clearer.  Should echo in class Baz be using FooType instead of T?

Comment: @Boon absolutely yes, my bad

Comment: Is BooleanLiteralType typealias declared inside the protocol related to the one declared outside of the protocol?

Comment: It will provide a default type for the alias, so in case the implementor of the protocol won't provide a typealias itself, it will default to `Bool`

Comment: @vadian says BooleanLiteralType typealias defined in the protocol is not related to the one outside.  You said the one outside is the default.  Which is correct? Does the doc specify this?

Comment: The proper name for this feature is *associated type*. Note also that once a protocol has associated types, you can use that protocol only as a generic constraint, not as the existential type of a variable or constant. That is, you can't do `func f(a: Foo)`, you can only do `func f<T: Foo>(a: T)`... but you gain the ability to do things like `func f<T: Foo where T.FooType == Comparable>(a: T)`.

Comment: @rickster So does the associated type relate to the typealias declared outside of the protocol? Does it assume the default of bool like Gariele mentioned?

Comment: @Boon it's just a matter of shadowing. They're not directly related, but when the typecheckers meets the `BooleanLiteralType` symbol it will check whether there's a local definition, then it will look in the global scope, finding the globally available `typealias` defined as `Bool`.

Comment: Thanks - can you show me where to find the info you just described, or prove it with code?

Answer (score 1):

Definition in the Swift Language Reference

> **Protocol Associated Type Declaration**
>
> Protocols declare associated types using the keyword typealias. An
>   associated type provides an alias for a type that is used as part of a
>   protocol’s declaration. Associated types are similar to type
>   parameters in generic parameter clauses, but they’re associated with
>   Self in the protocol in which they’re declared. In that context, Self
>   refers to the eventual type that conforms to the protocol. For more
>   information and examples, see Associated Types.

Comment: Thanks. Don't understand the documentation.  Can you explain? Is the BooleanLiteralType inside protocol type different from the one outside? What does it mean for the typealias to have nothing in the right side of the expression?

Comment: `BooleanLiteralType` in the protocol is a placeholder for the type which conforms to that protocol. In this case it must be a BooleanLiteralType

Comment: You mean BooleanLiteralType inside the protocol and outside are not related?

Comment: Yes, they are not related, inside the protocol it's a kind of a local type variable